# Audio playback lock screen control not displaying

Tags: swift, avplayer, avaudiosession

I am trying display audio controls on the lock screen, but the problem is the audio control does not display anything in the lock screen. I already enabled background modes and the audio plays in the background.

In app delegate class, right when my app launches, I set up my audio session

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    setupAudioSession()
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    return true
}

func setupAudioSession(){
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])
        self.becomeFirstResponder()

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

In my main controller, I call the setupLockScreen function after I play the audio.

```
func setupLockScreen(){
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
            self.player?.play()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }
    var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "My Song"
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = audioplayerItem.duration.seconds
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = audioplayerItem.asset.duration.seconds
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player?.rate

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
}
```

I read many articles and I looked all the qustions in Stack Overflow but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem that you `nowPlayingInfo` is not displaying on the lock screen or is it that the controls you added are not responding?

To have your `nowPlayingInfo` appear on the lockscreen, you need to do a few things [listed here in an answer on Handling External Player Events Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49025662/22147). One is to have a non mixable audio session (which you already have with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`) and the other is to be playing audio or only recently have stopped playing audio. Is your app actually playing audio?

Background audio, which you have is a sort of derived requirement,  because lockscreen=>background=>background audio needed to play audio, so I should add that to the other answer.

If the problem is that the lockscreen controls aren't enabled/responsive, then try adding a `pauseCommand` as well. The `playCommand`/`pauseCommand` pair seem to be a minimum requirement for receiving lockscreen/external player commands.

p.s. your `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime` looks wrong. shouldn't it be

```
nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioplayerItem.currentTime)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The 'non mixable audio session' is what solved it for me. When I had this as an option for my audio session in app delegate, the controls did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this (this is swift 3):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the pause command
        return .success
    }

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the play command
        return .success
    }

}
```

> This answer found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898041/9333764)

Comment: How is that different from what he's doing? Plus it just repeats the other answer's code; don't do that. A comment would have sufficed.